# JPA - Fetching data from one-to-one relation gives null

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jpa

When I save Relation entity which has one-to-one relation with WeeklyOccupancy everything works fine but when I try to retrieve data back then related entity is always null

I've tried fetching data by JpaRepository methods and by native queries

One directional one-to-one relation with join column configured in xml

```
            <one-to-one name="weeklyOccupancy" fetch="EAGER">
                <join-column name="W_OCCUPANCY_ID"/>
                <cascade>
                    <cascade-all/>
                </cascade>
            </one-to-one>
```

Data tables

```
CREATE TABLE RELATION (
  ID NUMBER(18) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  W_OCCUPANCY_ID NUMBER(18)
);

CREATE TABLE WEEKLY_OCCUPANCY (
    ID NUMBER(18) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

ALTER TABLE RELATION
    ADD CONSTRAINT RELATION_W_OCCUPANCY_FK
        FOREIGN KEY (W_OCCUPANCY_ID) REFERENCES WEEKLY_OCCUPANCY (ID);
```

Data is stored in a database but when I run

```
relationRepository.findAll()
```

using JpaRepository then I get relations but weeklyOccupancy which should be inside is always null.

I've tried also fetch data with nativeQuery:

```
 @Query(value = "select * from RELATION relation "
            + "LEFT JOIN WEEKLY_OCCUPANCY weeklyOccupancy ON relation.ID = 
             weeklyOccupancy.ID "
            + "WHERE ...", nativeQuery = true)
```

I've enabled spring.jpa.show-sql=true and I can see that select goes only for relation object, without any JOIN

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        relation0_.ID as ID1_0_,

        relation0_.W_OCCUPANCY_ID as W_OCCUPANCY_ID17_0_ from
        ...
        RELATION relation0_
```

I am really out of ideas, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your SQL query also return null values in WEEKLY_OCCUPANCY ? And you are sure that there is data in the DB?

Comment: When i retrieve data using JPA, all fields from 'Relation' entity are filled but the one with it has one-to-one relation is null. I am sure that data is in database because when I run the same native query that I've provided above direct in a database, I receive joined table with WeeklyOccupancy data inside.

Comment: It seems like jpa doesn't see relation between those two objects, when i run findAll() method from JpaRepository it queries only for Relation entity without any join. On the other hand when I run my native query with join inside it looks like jpa is not able to map fields from WeeklyOccupancy that are inside joined table to Relation Object